# Python have a class variable defined as an instance inside another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inner-classes

I am looking to have a class variable inside another class. Class A is what I want to have as an instance in class B. Somehow I get an error:

> new_B = B("Hello", new_A)
> TypeError: B() takes no arguments

I have read something about inner classes but don't understand how to apply constructors there.

```
class A:
    hp_id = ""

    def __init__(self, hp_id):
        self.hp_id = hp_id

class B:
    score = ""
    strand = A()

    def __int__(self, score, strand):
        self.score = score
        self.strand = strand

new_A = A("hello")
new_B = B("Hello", new_A)

print(new_B)
```

Comment: If you want class B to have all the attributes and methods of class A available, maybe inheritance would suit you better?

Comment: Apart from the typo in class B's `__init__`: You don't need `strand = A()` if you initialize it via  `__init__`.

Comment: @Timus, so I just leave that away. How is the type of the variable defined? I mean somehow it must know that it shall be an instance of A(). Don't I have to define that? Can I just initialize any type there?

Comment: In Python a variable doesn't have a type restriction. If you want type hints you could annote `__init__`, but that's no real restriction.

Comment: What does annote mean?

Comment: Check [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) and [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) as a good intro.

Answer (score 4):

Error is because you misspelled your B's constructor `__int__`